# Is there a smooth, spherically symmetric, static, asymptotically de Sitter spacetime of constant scalar curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, de-sitter-spacetime

...other than de Sitter space itself?  Two clarifications:

- I am not talking about solutions of Einstein's equations, just spacetimes.  So, general Lorentzian manifolds.
- I am not counting, for example, a Schwarzchild-de Sitter black hole, because although the scalar curvature $R$ is constant everywhere outside the singularity, it is basically a delta function at the singularity itself.  I'm only interested if the scalar curvature is constant *everywhere*.

Has this ever been studied?  Are there any?  Could there be any?

Comment: you can have Schwarzschild-de Sitter metric outside of some sphere and other non-singular metric inside, and connect the boundaries.

Comment: @Kosm  Hmm, very interesting.  So I guess I'm really thinking of a smooth manifold.  Then what you said wouldn't work, right?  I'll edit the question.

Comment: if you can match the two metrics, they can form a smooth manifold. See for example interior Schwarzschild metric. It can describe the inside of a massive non black hole object, while the exterior can be described by the usual Schwarzschild metric

Comment: @Kosm  Okay, okay, that is cool and I was not aware of it.  But doesn't that basically just make the problem harder, because then we need an interior metric that has constant scalar curvature and transitions smoothly to Schwarzchild-de Sitter space *over a finite radius*, instead of just at infinity?  Because the interior Schwarzchild metric surely doesn't have constant scalar curvature, right?  I know you're just offering some insight here and I do appreciate it either way.